# localStorage is not defined in Nextjs, Redux and Typescript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, next.js, react-typescript

I'm facing a problem with my project. The problem is  `ReferenceError: localStorage is not defined`. I'm using Nextjs, and Redux with Typescript.

[image: Screenshot_2]

```js
const storedUser: string | null = localStorage.getItem('user');
const user: DisplayUser | null = !!storedUser ? JSON.parse(storedUser) : null;

const storedJwt: string | null = localStorage.getItem('jwt');
const jwt: Jwt = !!storedJwt ? JSON.parse(storedJwt) : null;
```

I'm using these 2 variables  `user` and `jwt` in here `initialState`

```js
const initialState: AuthState = {
    user: user,
    jwt: jwt,
    isLoading: false,
    isSuccess: false,
    isError: false,
}
```

And `initialState` are used in `authSlice function`

```js
export const authSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'auth',
    initialState,
    reducers: {
        reset: (state) => {
            state.isLoading = false;
            state.isSuccess = false;
            state.isError = false;
        }
    },
})
```

Comment: `localStorage` is a *browser* feature. It does not exist in NodeJS.

Comment: @Pointy Than you to use it. please give an example.

Comment: I do not understand the question. You've provided your own example: `localStorage` either exists (in browser-side code) or not (in server-side code).

Comment: Please check the screenshot. I already add in my post. Actually This error showing in ta client side

Comment: Then why does the error say "Server Error"?

Comment: Actually, I really don't know what is happening. Right now I'm trying to add a condition and it's showing a new error. This is the link  https://prnt.sc/uVlJYyUKPKfF

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247799/discussion-between-shakib-d-shy-and-pointy).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have a similar issue like this in which I have to get the cart items from the localStorage and pass them to the initial state of redux. I solve it like this below code.

```
const getFromLocalStorage = (key: string) => {
  if (!key || typeof window === 'undefined') {
      return ""
  }
  return localStorage.getItem(key)
}
```

And then use it in initial state like below code:

```
export const initialState = { cartItems: getFromLocalStorage("cartItems") ? JSON.parse(getFromLocalStorage("cartItems") || '{}') : []};
```

Comment: Do you know how to store value in local storage using next js?

Comment: it is the same as we do in javascript or reactjs Example:   const handleIncreaseCart = () => {
    localStorage.setItem("nextjs", "store value in localstorage")
  }

Comment: hey brother this is working quite good but the only problem is that this is giving me two errors Error: Text content does not match server-rendered HTML.

Warning: Text content did not match. Server: "0" Client: "1"

can you please tell me why??

Answer (score 2):

If you are using `React.js` or `Next.js` and you want to check :

- if you are on the `Browser` (which means you **can** use the localStorage)
- or if you are on the `Server` (which means you **cannot** use localStorage)

You need to check if the `window` variable is not undefined, example :

```
if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {
  console.log('You are on the browser')
  // ️ can use localStorage here
} else {
  console.log('You are on the server')
  // ️ can't use localStorage
}
```

similar discussion on [github/vercel/next.js/discussions](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/19911)

Comment: How to use this in my code? Please give me an example.

Answer (score 1):

Adding onto Omar's answer - if you need to store something from `localStorage` in a Redux store, you'd need to grab that information client-side and then pass it into your initial Redux store. Redux itself will not be able to differentiate between client/server side rendering unless you check `typeof window !== 'undefined'`.

If you want to use Omar's answer as-is, you would need to make that calculation inside your Redux reducer when the initial state is being calculated. I don't recommend bringing that logic inside your reducer (makes it harder to unit test the reducer) - try calculating that logic outside of the initial Redux store, then pass it in (minimal example below)

```js
// However you calculate your initial Redux state should replace INITIAL_REDUX_STATE
const [statefulStore, setStatefulStore] = useState(INITIAL_REDUX_STATE);
const reduxStore = createStore(yourReducer, initialStore);
useEffect(() => {
  // Once and only once on the initial render, grab the localStorage value
  // and update Redux state
  setStatefulStore(oldState => {
    return Object.assign(oldState, {
      ssrValue: localStorage.getItem('user')
    });
  });
}, []);
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot run localStorage in Node because it's a browser feature. You can run a util and reuse it like this:

```
const getFromLocalStorage = (key) => {
    if (!key || typeof window === 'undefined') {
        return ""
    }
    return localStorage.getItem('user')
}
```

You can import this in other files and use it:

`const userId = getFromLocalStorage('userId');`

This is the simplest way of using this.

Answer (score 0):

Making a localStorage in Next.js persist is very frustrating, but it is possible, this is a link that I think would help one who wants to store some user preferences and settings, without setting or adding a modal and db to store the user's input. [How to persist data in Next.js with localStorage and no libraries.](https://esselr.vercel.app/thoughts/how-to-persist-and-access-data-in-next-js-using-localstorage-typescript)

Here is a [demo](https://nextlocalstorage.vercel.app/)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33920487)